# is it possible to use onDrag and onClick on Gridview in Android?

Tags: android

```
can i implement onClick & onDrag on GridView in Android ?
```

I have dynamic list of image, I am showing in GridView, now I'm trying to implement onDrag() doing some functionality and onClick() doing some functionality.

Comment: possible . please search on github ... you will get many sample code to habdle what you need

Comment: please try to find on google .... for some basic things ....